# xv drivers ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, gstreamer

I'm having a problem with the video output in Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). I tried to get a test video displayed on my screen (with gstreamer from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/using.html) )and I got different results for ximagesink and xvimagesink.

This is what I get from ximagesink

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! ximagesink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSink:ximagesink0: Output 
window was closed
Additional debug info:
ximagesink.c(700): gst_x_image_sink_handle_xevents (): 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSink:ximagesink0
Execution ended after 0:00:08.741734767
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
```

This is what I get from xvimagesink

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: 
Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1760): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
No Xv Port available
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Am I missing some drivers for Ubuntu ?

I don't know if it's relevant but I'm running Ubuntu from a virtual machine (Oracle VM virtualbox)

EDIT: 
output of 
    `lsmod | grep vbox`

```
vboxvideo              53248  2
ttm                    98304  1 vboxvideo
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 vboxvideo
vboxguest             294912  1 vboxvideo
drm                   352256  5 vboxvideo,ttm,drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  2 vboxvideo,drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  2 vboxvideo,drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  2 vboxvideo,drm_kms_helper
```

Comment: Did you install the guest additions?

Comment: I didn't. Looking through this site: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html it seems that some distributions already have all or a part of virtualbox guest additions . Is there a way for me to check if I have them or not ?

Comment: In a guest terminal `lsmod | grep vbox` will show you installed guest adddition modules. You'll need the `vboxvideo` driver.

Comment: @Takkat I have vboxvideo. I updated the question with the output of the command you suggested.